# Having a Web API that allows sending text to database and file upload to server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have an API that post text data to the database and another one that uploads file to AWS S3. Both of them works fine.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddStream(BusinessStream businessStream)
{
    var stream = new BusinessStream()
        {
            BusinessStreamId = Convert.ToInt64(212),
            BusinessStreamName = businessStream.BusinessStreamName

        };

    if (stream != null)
    {
        this.enugujobsdatabaseContext.BusinessStreams.Add(stream);
        this.enugujobsdatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    return Ok("Successfully added!");
}
```

This one allows sending text to the database successfully.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task Post(BusinessStream businessStream, IFormFile formFile)
{
     var client = new AmazonS3Client(AccessID, SecretKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
     var bucketExist = await AmazonS3Util.DoesS3BucketExistV2Async(client, BucketName);

     if (!bucketExist)
     {
         var bucketRequest = new PutBucketRequest()
                {
                    BucketName = BucketName,
                    UseClientRegion = true
                };

         await client.PutBucketAsync(bucketRequest);
     }

     var objectRequest = new PutObjectRequest()
            {
                BucketName = BucketName,
                Key = $"{DateTime.Now:yyyy\\/MM\\/dd\\/hhmmss}-{formFile.FileName }",
                InputStream = formFile.OpenReadStream(),
            };

     var response = await client.PutObjectAsync(objectRequest);
}
```

This other one uploads file to AWS S3. However, I want to merge both. Where the text to the database and the file upload can be done at the same time. What I tried is:

```
       [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PostTextAndFile(BusinessStream businessStream, IFormFile formFile)
    {
        var client = new AmazonS3Client(AccessID, SecretKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
        var bucketExist = await AmazonS3Util.DoesS3BucketExistV2Async(client, BucketName);

        var stream = new BusinessStream()
        {
            BusinessStreamId = Convert.ToInt64(1243),
            BusinessStreamName = businessStream.BusinessStreamName
        };

        if (stream != null)
        {
            if (!bucketExist)
            {
                var bucketRequest = new PutBucketRequest()
                {
                    BucketName = BucketName,
                    UseClientRegion = true
                };
                await client.PutBucketAsync(bucketRequest);
            }

            var objectRequest = new PutObjectRequest()
            {
                BucketName = BucketName,
                Key = $"{DateTime.Now:yyyy\\/MM\\/dd\\/hhmmss}-{formFile.FileName }",
                InputStream = formFile.OpenReadStream(),
            };
            var response = await client.PutObjectAsync(objectRequest);

            this.enugujobsdatabaseContext.BusinessStreams.Add(stream);
            this.enugujobsdatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

This is not working it does not even allow me to upload file and it gives 415 Error (Unsupported Media File)

Comment: Could you please tell me this 415 error is from the AWS or your web api?

Comment: The Error is from my API. it says 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: Could you please tell me how you build the request?